If $\tau_k:=\inf\{n>\tau_{k-1}:f(X_n)>0\}$, can we write $\tau_k=g(X_1,\ldots,X_{\tau_k})$ for some measurable $g$?
Let

$(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ and $(E,\mathcal E)$ be measurable spaces;
$(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$;
$f:E\to\mathbb R$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable.

Now let $\tau_0:=0$ and $$\tau_k:=\inf\{n>\tau_{k-1}:f(X_n)>0\}\;\;\;\text{for }k\in\mathbb N.$$ How can we show that $\tau_k$ can be written as $$\tau_k=g(X_1,\ldots,X_{\tau_k})\tag1$$ for some $\mathcal S$-measurable function $g:S\to(-\infty,\infty]$ and what is the measurable space $(S,\mathcal S)$?
I think a recursive definition of $g$ should be possible and maybe $S=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}E^n$ or something like that.

I guess $Z_n$ is $X_n$.  Please do not use $f$ for two different functions at once!

@GEdgar Thanks for mentioning. Fixed that.
